# Arabxetex: how to type eastern arabic numerals

Tags: xetex, arabic

how can I type eastern arabic numbers (or so called arabic indic) via arabxetex?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindu%E2%80%93Arabic_numeral_system

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_Arabic_numerals

note: I know that this can be done with polyglossia, but I am asking about arabxetex specifically.

Regards

Comment: Did you find the answer to your question?

Answer (score 4):

You would need to put your numbers inside `arab` environment or inside `\textarab` command argument:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{arabxetex}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{Times New Roman}
\begin{document}
\begin{arab}
01234
\end{arab}
or \textarab{01234}
\end{document}
```