# The best way to write arabic in beamer

Tags: beamer, arabic

I'm used to create  Arabic Beamer presentations with the  `arabtex` package, but with `arabtex` there are many environments (like `enumerate`) can not be used, for this I would like to write arabic using new packages such as `arabi` or `polyglossia` .

I tried writing my presentations with these new packages but  I always set problems of alignment especially with the `polyglossia` package .

My aim is to learn the best and easier way to create beamer presentation with arabic script with examples of that

my MWE with arabtex

```
\documentclass{beamer}  
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{arabtex}

\author{Me}
\title{Arabic in Beamer}

\begin{document}
\novocalize
\begin{frame}{}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{\begin{arabtext}
al-^sry.hT al-'awlY
\end{arabtext}}

\begin{arabtext}
$-1$ n.s `rby\\
$-2$ n.s `rby
\end{arabtext}

\begin{enumerate}
\item \RL{n.s `rby}
\item \RL{n.s `rby}
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your MWE works for me; exactly what problems are you experiencing?  At any rate, I’d recommend `arabxetex` compiled with `xelatex`.

Comment: Is your objection perhaps that the numerals in the enumeration are not those used in Arabic texts today?  If so, http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/53121/7883 and http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/98565/7883  and http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/172601/7883 may give you some ideas.

Comment: @Thérèse I have no broblems with my MWE , or with numerals i would like just  use arabic script with beamer, and to show numerals in bullet like standard enumerate (or itemize ) in latin script presentation.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to type your source in Arabic and not in ASCII transliteration?  If so, `arabxetex` makes that easy.

Comment: @Thérèse can you write an MWE with `arabxetex` in which you show list with numbers in bullet style (aligned to the right)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recent developements of `babel` (from v3.23) enabled to change direction of writing implicitely depending on script with option `bidi=basic`, it allow to overcome many obstacles to write a right to left beamer presentation.

Some minor changes remained I collected  in a class [`beamer-rl`](https://ctan.org/pkg/beamer-rl) which call babel with option `bidi=basic` and need `lualatex`

```
% compile with lualatex
% you can pass more babel option like this 
% \documentclass[babel={<babel options>}]{beamer-rl}
\documentclass{beamer-rl}   
\babelprovide[import=ar, main]{arabic}


\usetheme{Warsaw}
\begin{document}


\begin{frame}
\frametitle{الشريحة الأولى}

from wikipedia

اللُّغَة العَرَبِيّة هي أكثرُ اللغاتِ تحدثاً ونطقاً ضمن مجموعةِ اللغاتِ السامية، وإحدى أكثر
اللغات انتشاراً في العالم، يتحدثُها أكثرُ من 467 مليون نسمة، ويتوزعُ متحدثوها في 
الوطن العربي، بالإضافة إلى العديد من المناطق الأخرى المجاورة كالأهواز وتركيا وتشاد 
ومالي والسنغال وإرتيريا وإثيوبيا وجنوب السودان وإيران

\pause

\begin{enumerate}[<+-| alert@+>]
\item
نص عربي
\item
 نص عربي
\end{enumerate}    

\pause    

\begin{itemize}[<+-| alert@+>]
\item
 نص عربي 
\item
نص عربي
\end{itemize}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

This is not an answer but a clarification of the question, a clarification which won’t fit into a comment but which may put our wizards on the right track.

Here’s a small example (I use the `20pt` option only to make the image big and clear):

```
% compile with xelatex
\documentclass[20pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf]{arabxetex}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{Scheherazade}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{\textarab{الشريحة الأولى}}

  \begin{arab}
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item نص عربي
    \item نص عربي
    \end{enumerate}
  \end{arab}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of above code]

The problem is that, although the words go from right to left, as they should, they’re in the left part of the frame instead of the right.

`\usetheme{Singapore}` will put the title in the center, where it looks fine, but the enumeration is still on the left.  And `\usetheme{Warsaw}` makes the enumeration disappear altogether.  So I suspect that each theme will need its own patches…

Until a solution for `beamer` appears, you can make something suitable for presentations, though not as pretty as `beamer`, with `texpower` and the `screen` option of the `geometry` package:

```
% compile with xelatex
\documentclass[20pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage[screen]{geometry}
\usepackage[display]{texpower}
\usepackage[utf]{arabxetex}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=2]{Scheherazade}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{arab}
\section*{\textarab{الشريحة الأولى}}
\begin{enumerate}
\item نص عربي\pause
\item نص عربي
\end{enumerate}
\end{arab}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of second code sample]