# The RTL beamer Warsaw theme

Tags: beamer, formatting, arabic

I have asked a question in [RTL tableofcontents) in arabic (or polyglossia package) beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/223276/3954) and gotten my answer well by Seloumi. After thank him, 
 I have another question. How I can change position (and contents) of the black and blue header in Warsaw `beamer` theme as well as the direction of the text in them??

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need a redefinition of the `headline` template (as defined in the `split` outer theme used by `Warsaw`) to swap the two `beamercolorbox`es used there for the navigation bars:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}[circle]
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle continuation}{\gdef\beamer@frametitle{}} % framebreaks without numbering
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][right]% align the frametitle to the right
%\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{arabic}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\setotherlanguage[calendar=gregorian,numerals=maghrib]{arabic}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1]{B Nazanin}%
\newfontfamily\arabicfontsf[Script=Arabic,Scale=1]{B Nazanin}%
\graphicspath{{pics/}}
%
%~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\newcommand{\ar}{\textarabic} % to change the laguage in the section and frame title to persian
% This work as: \a{متن فارسی}
%~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~define bullet for enumerate~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\newcommand{\myenum}[1]
{
\par\vspace{3pt}\LR{\hspace*{3pt}%
\begin{pgfpicture}{-1ex}{-0.65ex}{1ex}{1ex}
\usebeamercolor[fg]{item projected}
{\pgftransformscale{1.8}\pgftext{\normalsize \pgfuseshading{bigsphere}}}
{\pgftransformshift{\pgfpoint{0pt}{0.5pt}}
\pgftext{\usebeamerfont*{item projected}\textcolor{white}{#1}}}
\end{pgfpicture}%
\hspace{1pt}%
}}
%~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~define bullet for itemize~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\newcommand{\myitem}{\par\vspace{3pt}\hspace{5mm}\LR{\hspace*{3pt}%
\begin{pgfpicture}{-1ex}{-0.65ex}{1ex}{1ex}
\usebeamercolor[fg]{item projected}
{\pgftransformscale{1.1}\pgftext{\normalsize\pgfuseshading{bigsphere}}}
\end{pgfpicture}%
\hspace{1pt}%
}}
%~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\newcommand{\myitemII}{\par\vspace{3pt}\hspace{5mm}\LR{\hspace*{3pt}%
\begin{pgfpicture}{-1ex}{-0.65ex}{1ex}{1ex}
\usebeamercolor[fg]{item projected}
{\pgftransformscale{1.8}\pgftext{\normalsize\pgfuseshading{bigsphere}}}
\end{pgfpicture}%
\hspace{1pt}%
}}
%*************************************************************************
%\addtobeamertemplate{block begin}{}{\justifying} %new code
%*************************************************************************
% change toc format ======================================================

\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}{%
\setRTL \myenum{\inserttocsectionnumber}
\inserttocsection\par
}

\setbeamertemplate{subsection in toc}{%
\setRTL \myitem
  \inserttocsubsection\par%
}

\setbeamertemplate{subsubsection in toc}{%
\setRTL \rightskip=3ex\myitem
  \inserttocsubsection\par%
}

\makeatletter
\defbeamertemplate*{headline}{arabic split theme}
{%
  \leavevmode%
  \@tempdimb=2.4375ex%
  \ifnum\beamer@subsectionmax<\beamer@sectionmax%
    \multiply\@tempdimb by\beamer@sectionmax%
  \else%
    \multiply\@tempdimb by\beamer@subsectionmax%
  \fi%
  \ifdim\@tempdimb>0pt%
    \advance\@tempdimb by 1.825ex%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=\@tempdimb]{subsection in head/foot}%
      \vbox to\@tempdimb{\vfil\insertsubsectionnavigation{.5\paperwidth}\vfil}%
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=\@tempdimb]{section in head/foot}%
      \vbox to\@tempdimb{\vfil\insertsectionnavigation{.5\paperwidth}\vfil}%
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \fi%
}
\makeatother

%=================================================================

\begin{document}
%\selectlanguage{arabic}
\title{\textarabic{بعنوان عنوان نعنوان }}
\author{AUTHOR}
\date{\today}

\section{\textarabic{مقدمه}}
\begin{frame} \ar{متن فارسی .....} \end{frame}
\subsection{\textarabic{مایع }}
\begin{frame} \ar{متن فارسی .....} \end{frame}
\section{\textarabic{سیستمهای فرمیونی همبسته:مایع}}
\begin{frame} \ar{متن فارسی .....} \end{frame}
\subsection{\textarabic{متن فارسی .....}}
\begin{frame} \ar{متن فارسی .....} \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

A zoomed-in image of the new `headline`:

[image]