# The tableofcontents in beamer arabic

Tags: beamer, polyglossia, arabic, right-to-left

I have asked two question about arabic beamer in the following link:
[RTL tableofcontents) in arabic (or polyglossia package) beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/223276/rtl-tableofcontents-in-arabic-or-polyglossia-package-beamer/223401?noredirect=1#comment525126_223401)

And they have solved well. Now i have a problem. When I have designed all my slides, the number of tableofcontents items became more than one frame. **I have used the [allowframebebreaks] option but the problem has not be solved. How i can show the tableofcontents in more than one slide (in one column) in beamer arabic?**
[image]

Comment: You could use a two column toc http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/136082/36296

Answer (score 1, accepted):

at first i don't know how to help you with diplaying the table of contents on two slides.

But i suggest something else which is a good strategy in presentations i think.
Limit the table of contents to display only the sections with these two statements:

```
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{1}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
```

This way your table of contents on the second slide will show the sections you are going to cover in your presentation.
On a slide at the beginning of a certain section you can show the subsections of this section. On this slide the other sections can be grayed out.
I do this by:

```
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\begin{frame}{Navigation}
\tableofcontents[currentsection]
\end{frame}
```

I hope that this solves youre problem in a way you like.

Answer (score 3):

If your toc is longer then a frame you can split it manually using  the command `\tableofcontents[sections={1-6}]` to show sections from 1 to 6 in the first frame , and the others sections can be placed on the next frame like this :

```
\frame{
    \frametitle{\textarabic{فهرست مطالب}}
    \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
    \begin{Arabic}
    \tableofcontents[sections={1-6}]
    \end{Arabic}
    \end{minipage}
    }
\frame{
    \frametitle{\textarabic{فهرست مطالب}}
    \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
    \begin{Arabic}
    \tableofcontents[sections={7-12}]
    \end{Arabic}
    \end{minipage}
    }
```