# How to get alignment of TOC right in a Beamer with RTL language?

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents, horizontal-alignment, right-to-left, bullets

I get this bad alignment of bullets inside the TOC using the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[numerals=mashriq,abjadjimnotail=true]{arabic} % Polyglossia package for more options
\setotherlanguages{english}
\setsansfont[Script=Arabic,Ligatures=TeX]{Simplified Arabic} % Bold sans used for sections
\newfontfamily\englishfont{Arial}

\usetheme{Frankfurt}

\title{مثال تجريبي للمشكلة}

\AtBeginSection[] % Do nothing for \section*
{   %
  \begin{frame}
    \frametitle[TOC]{المحتويات}
    \tableofcontents[currentsection,currentsubsection,subsubsectionstyle=hide/hide]
  \end{frame}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \titlepage%
\end{frame}

\section*{المحتويات}
\frame{\tableofcontents[subsubsectionstyle=hide/hide]} %this is the first slide of TOC

\section{مقدمة}

\section{الفصل الاول}

\section{الفصل الثاني - تفاصيل عن الموضوع}

\section {الفصل الثالث}

\end{document}
```

**Output**

[image]

So my question is there any way to get the alignment right?

Comment: does http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/223276/rtl-tableofcontents-in-arabic-or-polyglossia-package-beamer help?

Comment: yes, thanks that gave me the clue to the `\minipage` solution.

Answer (score 1):

Well after doing some research on similar posts. I found that surrounding the `\tableofcontents` with `minipage` environment is necessary to get alignment right.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[numerals=mashriq,abjadjimnotail=true]{arabic} % Polyglossia package for more options
\setotherlanguages{english}
\setsansfont[Script=Arabic,Ligatures=TeX]{Simplified Arabic} % Bold sans used for sections
\newfontfamily\englishfont{Arial}

\usetheme{Frankfurt}

\title{مثال تجريبي للمشكلة}

\AtBeginSection[] % Do nothing for \section*
{   %
  \
  \begin{minipage}{1.0\linewidth}
  \begin{frame}
    \frametitle[TOC]{المحتويات}
    \tableofcontents[currentsection,currentsubsection,subsubsectionstyle=hide/hide]
  \end{frame}    
  \end{minipage}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \titlepage%
\end{frame}

\section*{المحتويات}
\begin{minipage}{1.0\linewidth}
\frame{\tableofcontents[subsubsectionstyle=hide/hide]} %this is the first slide of TOC  
\end{minipage}

\section{مقدمة}

\section{الفصل الاول}

\section{الفصل الثاني - تفاصيل عن الموضوع}

\section {الفصل الثالث}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Something rather simple that worked for me was using `ragged2e` and the provided environment `FlushRight`:

```latex
\documentclass{beamer}
% polyglossia and all that
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{TOC}

\begin{FlushRight}
\tableofcontents
\end{FlushRight}

\end{frame}

\section{sec 1}

\section{sec 2}

% ...

\end{document}
```