# using block environment for arabic/persian Beamer and right alignment

Tags: beamer, environments, arabic, block

I have a problem with block environment in Beamer. I am using persian/arabic language. For the block environment, I want the title of the block and the text inside the block be aligned on the right hand side but they are aligned on the left hand side. I saw the guidance of Salim Bou in the following link for the itemize and enumeration environment that were so useful but for the block environment I am totally confused .
[The best way to write arabic in beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/197575/the-best-way-to-write-arabic-in-beamer)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) can you provide a MWE (minimal working example) which show your problem.