# How to align an English paragraph left and write English numbers in English in a Persian beamer?

Tags: beamer, bidi, persian

I am working on a presentation with beamer class in Persian and I have some problems with bilingual text. For writing left to right I use \LR command and it works, but the English is not aligned left. Especially in "itemize" environment it is very annoying. It seems that "latin" environment does not work in persian beamer. In addition the English numbers are shown in Persian. 
The sample code is as below:

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}

\usepackage[persian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont[Script=Arabic,Numbers=Arabic]{XB Zar} 
\setsansfont[Script=Arabic,Numbers=Arabic]{XB Zar} 

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
یک متن پارسی \\
\LR{An english text with some numbers like 10, 11, 12, ...}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I can’t compile your example: `babel` has no `persian` option.  And you’re using `fontspec`, you shouldn’t be using `inputenc` and `times`.

Comment: Please excuse if I mix up things (I don't know anything about right-to-left languages), but maybe http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/197575/the-best-way-to-write-arabic-in-beamer can help

Comment: Some parts of your example suggest that you’re compiling your document with `pdflatex` (and then you probably need `arabtex`), while other parts suggest that you’re compiling with `xelatex` (and then you should look at `xepersian` and `bidipresentation`).  Which do you want to use?

Comment: I have found some part of my question, but some part of it is still unanswered. I can write the English numbers in English by putting them between two $, but I still can not align the English text left. I think some part of the problem is rooted in "babel" package. If it was possible that the "Latin" environment work in Persian beamer,  the problem would be solved. I am compiling the document with lualatex and it ends in error with xelatex.

Comment: @YousefAhmadi Can you edit your question and include how far you have come?

Comment: Concerning the alignment, have you tried thinks like the `flushleft` environment for the English text? Can't try, as your example only creates errors for me.

Comment: I can use \flushleft (in Persian beamer \flushright), but I will loose justifying and itemizing. However, I have solved my problem temporarily by \flushright command, but in a stupid way. I have used a lot of \hspace commands to manually justify the text and put each item in a separate itemize environment.