# Table of content with Arabic language

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents

I have used the answer from this question **The best way to write Arabic in beamer by (Salim Bou)  [see here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/197575/the-best-way-to-write-arabic-in-beamer)**, but still there is a problem with the table of content, it should be aligned to right instead of being centered, see the picture below, any help please?

[image]

the code sample is:

```
% compile with xelatex

\documentclass[xcolor=table]{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[calendar=gregorian,numerals=maghrib]{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{Simplified Arabic}
\newfontfamily\arabicfontsf[Script=Arabic]{Simplified Arabic}

% for RTL liste
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\RTList}{\raggedleft\rightskip\@totalleftmargin}
\makeatother

 % RTL frame title
 \setbeamertemplate{frametitle}
 {\vspace*{-1mm}
 \nointerlineskip
 \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=0.3cm,ht=2.2em,wd=\paperwidth]{frametitle}
 \vbox{}\vskip-2ex%
 \strut\hskip1ex\insertframetitle\strut
 \vskip-0.8ex%
 \end{beamercolorbox}
  }

 % RTL triangle for itemize
 \setbeamertemplate{itemize item}  
 {\scriptsize\raise1.25pt\hbox{\donotcoloroutermaths$\blacktriangleleft$}} 

\newcommand\Fontvi{\fontsize{14}{10}\selectfont}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{المحتويات}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\rightskip\rightmargin

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
\frametitle{الشريحة الاولى}
\begin{block}{ادارة الحالات}
حالة جيدة
\end{block}

\end{frame}

\section{الدراسة المرجعية}
\subsection{مراحل الدراسة المرجعية}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
\frametitle{الشريحة الاولى}
\begin{block}{ادارة الحالات}
حالة جيدة
\end{block}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.Stackexchange! What do you want to change?

Comment: And which of the answers did you use? Please make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that reproduces your picture.

Comment: What is your exact problem?

Comment: I add a minimal example to produce this slide.
the exact problem is that the toc should be aligned to right not to be centered or cluttered like the picture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could wrap the table of contents in a `minipage` of suitable width:

```
% !TeX program = xelatex
\documentclass[xcolor=table]{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[calendar=gregorian,numerals=maghrib]{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{Times New Roman}
\newfontfamily\arabicfontsf[Script=Arabic]{Times New Roman}

\setbeamertemplate{subsection in toc}[ball unnumbered]

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{المحتويات}
\begin{minipage}{.85\textwidth} 
    \tableofcontents
\end{minipage}
\end{frame}

\section{الدراسة المرجعية}
\subsection{مراحل الدراسة المرجعية}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is great thank you for your time, you solve the problem, but the subsection in toc should be aligned a little bit to the left right?

Comment: @AliMhrez Please see my edited answer

Comment: Thank you a lot, your answer solves the problem , I appreciate your help