# itemize inside the block in beamer ARABIC RTL Polyglossia

Tags: beamer, itemize, polyglossia

I want to create a presentation to be able to put itemize inside the block in beamer.

```
    \documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[numerals=maghrib,locale=algeria]{arabic} 
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{Amiri}
\newfontfamily\arabicfontsf[Script=Arabic]{Amiri}

\usetheme{Warsaw}
\rightskip\rightmargin

\title{بسم الله الرحمان الرحيم \\
\textcolor{yellow}{محسن}}

\author{\textenglish{Mohcine}}
\institute{فئة المستهدفة}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\maketitle
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Title Frame}
 \frametitle{تمارين رقم 1}
    \begin{block}{تمارين رقم 1}
    {
       أدرس قابلية اشتقاق الدالة في النقطة  في كل حالة مما يلي ثم اكتب معادلة المماس في هذه النقطة:
\begin{itemize}
\item $f(x)=5x-3$ و $x_{0}=2$
\item $f(x)=3x^2-2x+5$ و $x_{0}=0$
\item $f(x)=\sin x$ و $x_{0}=\dfrac{\pi}{2}$
\item $f(x)=\cos 2x$ و $x_{0}=\dfrac{\pi}{3}$
\item $f(x)=\tan x$ و $x_{0}=0$
\item $f(x)=-\dfrac{1}{2}x^{3}+x^{2}$ و $x_{0}=2$
\item $f(x)=-\dfrac{x+1}{x+2}$ و $x_{0}=1$
\end{itemize}
    }
    \end{block}
        \end{frame}


\end{document}
```

which produces the following image

[image]

Comment: Writing beamer presentation for RTL languages (xelatex engine) still facing some issues best to use lualatex with beamer-rl class https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/511186/54817

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a way

```
\begin{itemize}\itemindent=1.75em
\item $f(x)=5x-3$ و $x_{0}=2$
...
\end{itemize}
```

OR def **bitemize** environment for block itemize.

```
%+++++++++++++++++ def block itemize
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{bitemize}{%
  \ifnum\@itemdepth >2\relax\@toodeep\else%
      \advance\@itemdepth\@ne%
      \beamer@computepref\@itemdepth%
      \usebeamerfont{itemize/enumerate \beameritemnestingprefix body}%
      \usebeamercolor[fg]{itemize/enumerate \beameritemnestingprefix body}%
      \usebeamertemplate{itemize/enumerate \beameritemnestingprefix body begin}%
      \begin{list}
        {%
            \usebeamertemplate{itemize \beameritemnestingprefix item}%
        }%
        { \itemindent=1.75em%
            \def\makelabel##1{%
              {%  
                  \hss\llap{{%
                    \usebeamerfont*{itemize \beameritemnestingprefix item}%
                        \usebeamercolor[fg]{itemize \beameritemnestingprefix item}##1}}%
              }%  
            }%  
        }
        \raggedright
  \fi
}
{
  \end{list}
  \usebeamertemplate{itemize/enumerate \beameritemnestingprefix body end}%
}
\expandafter\let\csname beamer@@tmpop@itemize item@default\endcsname\relax
\expandafter\let\csname beamer@@tmpop@itemize subitem@default\endcsname\relax
\expandafter\let\csname beamer@@tmpop@itemize subsubitem@default\endcsname\relax
\makeatother
%+++++++++++++++++
```

The editing of your code is as follows.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[numerals=maghrib,locale=algeria]{arabic} 
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{Amiri}
\newfontfamily\arabicfontsf[Script=Arabic]{Amiri}

\usetheme{Warsaw}
\rightskip\rightmargin

\title{بسم الله الرحمان الرحيم \\
\textcolor{yellow}{محسن}}

\author{\textenglish{Mohcine}}
\institute{فئة المستهدفة}
\date{\today}


%+++++++++++++++++ def block itemize
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{bitemize}{%
  \ifnum\@itemdepth >2\relax\@toodeep\else%
      \advance\@itemdepth\@ne%
      \beamer@computepref\@itemdepth%
      \usebeamerfont{itemize/enumerate \beameritemnestingprefix body}%
      \usebeamercolor[fg]{itemize/enumerate \beameritemnestingprefix body}%
      \usebeamertemplate{itemize/enumerate \beameritemnestingprefix body begin}%
      \begin{list}
        {%
            \usebeamertemplate{itemize \beameritemnestingprefix item}%
        }%
        { \itemindent=1.75em%
            \def\makelabel##1{%
              {%  
                  \hss\llap{{%
                    \usebeamerfont*{itemize \beameritemnestingprefix item}%
                        \usebeamercolor[fg]{itemize \beameritemnestingprefix item}##1}}%
              }%  
            }%  
        }
        \raggedright
  \fi
}
{
  \end{list}
  \usebeamertemplate{itemize/enumerate \beameritemnestingprefix body end}%
}
\expandafter\let\csname beamer@@tmpop@itemize item@default\endcsname\relax
\expandafter\let\csname beamer@@tmpop@itemize subitem@default\endcsname\relax
\expandafter\let\csname beamer@@tmpop@itemize subsubitem@default\endcsname\relax
\makeatother
%+++++++++++++++++


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\maketitle
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
 \frametitle{تمارين رقم 1}
 \begin{block}{تمارين رقم 1}
       أدرس قابلية اشتقاق الدالة في النقطة  في كل حالة مما يلي ثم اكتب معادلة المماس في هذه النقطة:
\begin{itemize}\itemindent=1.75em
\item $f(x)=5x-3$ و $x_{0}=2$
\item $f(x)=3x^2-2x+5$ و $x_{0}=0$
\item $f(x)=\sin x$ و $x_{0}=\dfrac{\pi}{2}$
\item $f(x)=\cos 2x$ و $x_{0}=\dfrac{\pi}{3}$
\item $f(x)=\tan x$ و $x_{0}=0$
\item $f(x)=-\dfrac{1}{2}x^{3}+x^{2}$ و $x_{0}=2$
\item $f(x)=-\dfrac{x+1}{x+2}$ و $x_{0}=1$
\end{itemize}
\end{block}
 \end{frame}

\begin{frame}
 \frametitle{تمارين رقم 2}
 \begin{block}{تمارين رقم 2}
       أدرس قابلية اشتقاق الدالة في النقطة  في كل حالة مما يلي ثم اكتب معادلة المماس في هذه النقطة:
\begin{bitemize}
\item $f(x)=5x-3$ و $x_{0}=2$
\item $f(x)=3x^2-2x+5$ و $x_{0}=0$
\item $f(x)=\sin x$ و $x_{0}=\dfrac{\pi}{2}$
\item $f(x)=\cos 2x$ و $x_{0}=\dfrac{\pi}{3}$
\item $f(x)=\tan x$ و $x_{0}=0$
\item $f(x)=-\dfrac{1}{2}x^{3}+x^{2}$ و $x_{0}=2$
\item $f(x)=-\dfrac{x+1}{x+2}$ و $x_{0}=1$
\end{bitemize}
\end{block}
 \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

output with TexLive 2019:

[image]

Comment: Please, How can I add symbole like number instead of bullet to bitemize

Comment: can we flush left the itemize list from left to right???